# How to inject dependencies in a BaseFragment/BaseActivity using Hilt?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var eventTracker: Provider<EventTracker>

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        eventTracker.get().trackScreenInteraction(this.javaClass.canonicalName)
    }
}
```

I am trying to do this; but it gives me a `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property eventTracker has not been initialized`

Comment: Did you mark the activity/fragment with `@AndroidEntryPoint` ?

Comment: The SubClass who is using it yes. Not this guy. 
I tried making this guy `@AndroidEntryPoint` too but that didn't even compile.

Comment: So @theapache64 you were right. The starting fragment was not marked with `@AndroidEntryPoint`. Silly me.

Comment: I had the same exact problem when trying to log screen views with an injected analytics class just like you. I checked my Fragments over and over and I thought all of them were annotated with @AndroidEntryPoint. Turns out a I missed a few. The Fragments that were missing it were Fragments that lived inside a ViewPager. So if anyone else is running into this, make sure you check your ViewPager Fragments as well!